# how do i print by twos in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

**Code**

```
int Y;

System.out.print("Enter num1: ");
Y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

for (int X = 0; X < Y; X++){
    System.out.println(X); 
}
```

**current output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

**desired output:**

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

Comment: Use print instead of println, then call println on odd values of X

Comment: Or use `X+=2` instead of `X++` and `print(X)` and then `println(" " + X);`

Comment: As a side note, you should follow java naming conventions and call your variables `x` and `y` (lower case) instead of `X` and `Y` (upper case).

Comment: Thank you both for your input! + I will name my variables lowercase from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add small check and println once condition met on `X`

```
    int Y=5;
    for (int X = 0; X <= Y; X++){
         System.out.print(X+" ");
        if(X%2!=0)// Add a new line only if condition met i.e on odds
            System.out.println();
    }
```

output

```
 0 1
 2 3
 4 5
```

Comment: `System.out.print(X+" ");`  if you wan space in between

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<Y){
        String op = "" + i;
        if(i+1 < Y)
            op += " " + (i+1);
        System.out.println(op);
        i=i+2;
    }
```